# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'people'

Tags: python, cmd

Выдаёт ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'people'
причём не в коде python а при скачивании sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
что делать помогите пожалуйста !
Кстати вот ещё о проблеме

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[~]
└─# add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 362, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 345, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 86, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
       ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 126, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 113, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'people'
```

Comment: Все таки, сначала надо попробовать загуглить вашу проблему, иногда даже в тупую загуглив саму ошибку, прежде чем бить тревогу и писать на StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказано [здесь](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1891547.html), вам нужно установить `python3-launchpadlib` и запустить процесс заново. То же самое вам советуют на сайте [linux questions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/debian-bullseye-sid-add-apt-repository-not-working-python-problem-4175720821/)